# Laravel 5.6 - Exception Handler to handle Internal Server Error (500) for Api

Tags: exception, laravel-5.6

In laravel we can handle exceptions as follows:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException or $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found',
            ], 404);
        }


    }


    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

However when there is a internal server error the application returns the `Whoops something went wrong` page if in production or a stack trace if in debug.

How can I handle a internal server error when using an api which expects json?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add another check on an `ErrorException`, inside the `render()` (app/Exceptions/Handler.php) method:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException or $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) 
        {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found',
            ], 404);
        }
    }

    // ==> Add this check
    if ($exception instanceof ErrorException) 
    {
        if($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) 
        {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Something went wrong on our side',
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: that only works if the error is instanceof of  `\ErrorException` if there an database error e.g. integrity contraint violation then the above doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use `try {} catch {}` the event that could throw a 500 error, and catch an `ErrorException` or the generic `Exception`. Alternatively you could manually throw an exception at that point.

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround:

```
if (!$this->isHttpException($exception)) 
{
    if($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) 
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Something went wrong on our side',
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a nice solution, but keep in mind that any other HTTP error will be handled at the default way (error view for most common errors). So other than 500 or 404.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was my **.htaccess** file, I didn't have the proper configuration. *(My environment was with Laravel 5.6, Bitmani LAMP)*

The **.htaccess** must have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

That worked for me, that fixed my *"Internal Server Error (500)"* in my API. And one recommendation is that you check the apache log (error_log and access_log), they can give you more information.

I hope it helps you.